# Detect client disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a very simple socket.io connection.  My server does the following:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("CONNECTED ON SERVER");                                 
    socket.emit("connected", "CONNECTED!");                                     
});
```

Indeed, the client gets the "CONNECTED!" message.

I need to be able to detect when a client disconnects and take some action.  I've tried:

```
io.sockets.on("disconnect", function (socket) {                                 
    console.log("DISCONNECTED!");                                 
});
```

...but this does not log "DISCONNECTED!" on the server.  However, `CONNECTED ON SERVER` from above *does* get logged.

I know that the socket can detect the disconnect because once I close the browser window, the server logs out:

> info  - transport end (socket end)
>     debug - set close timeout for client 
>     debug - cleared close timeout for client 
>     debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 
>     debug - discarding transport

This means that `socket.io` *is* able to detect that the client connection closed.  How can *I* detect that it was closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the event on each socket itself

You can see on their [how to use page](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) they set the disconnect event on the actual socket:

```
// note, io.listen(<port>) will create a http server for you
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.sockets.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone'});

  socket.on('private message', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.sockets.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

If you take a look in the socket.io code (of at least v0.10.20) you will see that `io.sockets` is a SocketNamespace object (from namespace.js), and in that is the `handlePacket` function

the connection packet does

```
self.$emit('connection', socket);
```

Which will send the event to its own EventEmitter stuff.

Where as the disconnect packet is done this way:

```
socket.$emit('disconnect', packet.reason || 'packet');
```

So the disconnect event is never fired for the namespace object.

The current github code shows that they have moved the packet handling to their respective classes

[connection emission in namespace.js Line 172](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/namespace.js#L172)

```
// fire user-set events
self.emit('connect', socket);
self.emit('connection', socket);
```

[disconnect emission in socket.js Line 370](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L370)

```
 ...
 this.disconnected = true;
 delete this.nsp.connected[this.id];
 this.emit('disconnect', reason);
};
```