# How to make a timestamp login form

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a javascript webpage or an executive file (.exe) that will ask users to login for payroll below are the details I will need

what time, date they logged in 
what time, date they logged out
Their name (username?)

It's basically needed so I can calculate payroll on a computer at reception that employees can use. This would make my life easier so I can keep track of the payroll for them as they are hourly paid people.

I will also need this information saved/logged on a file that I can later utilize to calculate the pays for these people.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <font size="6">Username:</font>
        <input type="text" style="font-size:30px;height:45px;width:300px;" name="username" id="username"/>
        <br>
        <font size="6">Password:</font>
        <input type="password" style="font-size:30px;height:45px;width:300px;" name="password" id="password"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" style="font-size:30px;height:45px;width:300px;" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The timestamp of the login is generally saved in the database and set by the server not the client (to prevent users from being able to set it themselves).

Comment: What does the "or .exe" part mean here? That's so completely off-base from this question.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance consider using services like [Arc](https://arc.dev/), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 0):

I made a whole web portal to solve your problem. It has Nodejs on backend and Mongodb as database

*screenshots and link given below =>*

**This is the login page**

[image]

**This is the register page**

[image]

**This is the forget password page**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**This is the employee dashboard page**

[image]

**This is the admin dashboard page**

[image]

**This is the custom 404 page**

[image]

**This is the mongo database collection**

[image]

[image]

**This is the link to the website**
(this site is currently hosted on heroku's free tier hosting so please be patient while it loads.
Once its on the paid hosting it will load fast. )

*For your ease here are two test account credentials =>*

1. For employee sample account =>

> ```
>  username = sam
>  password = 123
> ```

2. For admin sample account =>

> ```
> username = danyal
> password = 123
> ```

**Link**: [Click me!](https://payroll-tracker-app.herokuapp.com)

Github Repo

> https://github.com/sjcodebook/payroll-time-tracker-nodejs

hope it helps.

Comment: This answer has a lot of ambition, but it comes across as a marketing pitch for services. Maybe you should try and engage as a contractor?

Answer (score -1):

I invite you to read this post:
[Detect client disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315759/detect-client-disconnect)

Reading this one, you will be able to know when they're connecting.

Comment: What? Clients can disconnect for a multitude of reasons, some just WiFi related.